# Is overloading wrong to use in this case?

Tags: java, arraylist, overloading

I have a method that list the elements of an ArrayList, typically it prints the components of a global variable ArrayList, but in one specific instance I need it to print the components of a local variable.

So I have this

```
public static void listPlayers(ArrayList<Player> characters, boolean beingRolled) {
    //print character components (beingRolled specifies which parts of each players to print
}
```

and I use that when I'm using the local variable ArrayList,
when I want to use the global i call this version

```
public static void listPlayers(boolean beingRolled) {
    listPlayers(players, abitraryBoolean);
}
```

where players is  the global variable

Another thing I was thinking about is anywhere I want to use the global I could pass a null reference for characters and write this method

```
public static void listPlayers(ArrayList<Player> characters, boolean beingRolled) {
    if (characters == null) characters = players;
    //print components
}
```

Which is the more professional/recommended version?

Comment: If you know at every call site whether you want to output the global or parameter, the first variation is probably preferable. Passing null when you want to output the global just obfuscates things.

Comment: In this particular case, you may want to reconsider the use of a global variable to start with.

Comment: Why do you even need `public static void listPlayers(boolean beingRolled)`? Can't you just call `listPlayers(players, abitraryBoolean);` directly?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm using a global (static) variable because there will only ever be one instance of the object, and it's what actually runs the program. I have global variables for the ArrayList, the File it's saved in, and a scanner just because i got _really_ tired of opening and closing the scanner in every method that requires input. The main method runs an infinite (until the user types the 'end' command) loop that gets a command and then calls the methods that either modify, save, or print the ArrayList. is that bad practice?

Comment: @Wasdo: In this case it's probably acceptable practice, but if you have time to worry about whether overloading is a code smell, you certainly have time to worry about globals.

Comment: @NathanTuggy so you would suggest refactoring so they are all local variables and passed as paramters?

Comment: @Wasdo: Not necessarily; there are other ways to address that. For example, as [Ryan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28711472/4099598) suggests, using class-scoped state by passing the ArrayList into the constructor of an appropriately-sized class that contains the method in question. If possible, use a DI framework to then make the construction implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, stay away from null; the overloaded method signature is a better approach.

That said, one thing you said is scary -- You have a static method operating on a global variable.  In general, that is a bad idea.  You should consider refactoring to use Object/class scoped state, rather than global, static scoped state.

I would even go so far as to say that you should only use the overload that takes the ArrayList as a parameter, and pass it the global variable every time.  Then, even if you must use a global variable, at least you're using it in one fewer place.

Edit: One of my professors back in college wrote a book on refactoring that is very readable and has a lot of good content (though the typography is a bit odd).  It's called `Principle-Based Refactoring: Learning Software Design Principles by Applying Refactoring Rules`, by Steve Halladay.  I highly suggest reading the first half (second half is essentially a reference).

Comment: In general, I don't use non-final static variables.  It sounds like you are describing the textbook use case for a Singleton; if that's true, then yes, a static variable is acceptable.  However, realize that if you are in the habit of using global variables, that will limit your ability to reuse your code, as a Singleton variable is usually not the right design for the next project you want to use your code in.

Answer (score 0):

The first version is better because it is easier for someone else to understand. When a function's arguments are all listed, the caller can more easily predict what the function will do. If the function relies on variables which are not visible, say if this is available in a library without the source, the caller will not understand why the function acts in an unexpected way. This would be impossible to understand without good documentation.